# Arangodump misses some data

Tags: arangodb

I'm using arangodb 3.1.25. I found that some data is missed inside dump directory after execution of such command using 'arangodump':

```
arangodump --server.endpoint tcp://address:port --server.database DbName --dump-data true --server.password=**** --include-system-collections true --output-directory "dump" -overwrite true
```

Example of data that is missed:

On the original database(let's name it 'test') i have such documents in collection 'interchange_edges':

```
{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_to":"parts/64020","type":"interchange"}

{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_to":"parts/44474","type":"interchange"}

{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_to":"parts/48761","type":"interchange"}
```

Then i execute dump using instruction listed above and then i open a file with dumped data for my collection. In my case it have name interchange_edges_7d8fd33864b65edab6a05b838483239b.data.json. Then i search in this file by substring '66430' because all original records have this substring. As a result i found such matches:

```
{"type":2300,"data":{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_id":"interchange_edges/66430_64020","_key":"66430_64020","_rev":"_V8MSKAS--C","_to":"parts/64020","type":"interchange"}}

{"type":2300,"data":{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_id":"interchange_edges/66430_64020","_key":"66430_64020","_rev":"_V8MSKAS--C","_to":"parts/64020","type":"interchange"}}

{"type":2300,"data":{"_from":"interchange_headers/66430","_id":"interchange_edges/66430_64020","_key":"66430_64020","_rev":"_V8MSKAS--C","_to":"parts/64020","type":"interchange"}}
```

Somehow i have 3 (duplicated?) rows instead of 3 different rows as expected.

What may cause this behaviour? Did i missed something critical?

Some information about environment:
*arangosh (ArangoDB 3.1.25 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014)*

Comment: What data is missing?

Comment: Some of the records that are represented in datasource are not insode given dump directory. I'm not sure that sharing of actual content will make sense..

Comment: records meaning documents or collections or indexes are missing? no nothing should be missing from a database that is dumped as above. of course no other but the database `DbName` is  restored with the above command.

Comment: Do all collections exist? Or are some missing? What are their names and what is your operating system? Or are certain records missing? Can you show that they exist as live documents in the database, e.g. using arangosh or the Web UI, and that the document with this exact key is not contained in the JSON dump?

Comment: Please look into updated description

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [ArangoDB 3.1 is end of life](https://www.arangodb.com/eol-notice/) since a while now.

**The Problems described below are specific to the MMFiles-Storageengine.**

At the start of a dump, ArangoDump will invoke the wal collection flushing mechanism.

This will collect all documents from the WAL-files to their specific datafiles. After having waited for a while for the server to have completed that, ArangoDump will start to draw the collection files from the server.

Documents that haven't been collected from the wAL-files into the collection files will not be part of the dump.

Hence you have several options here:

- You should run the latest release of a release series - 3.1.29 here.
- run the WAL-collection manually and observe whether the server actually deletes the WAL-files.
- keep a backup of the database files, and upgrade to a supported ArangoDB version
- use the slower ArangoExport of a later ArangoDB Version to export collection by collection